# How to return the row from a data frame based on the maximum value of the data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, max

Suppose I have got a data frame as displayed below. Most of the suggestions I found on Stackoverflow aim at getting the max from **one** column and then returning the row index.
I was wondering whether there is a way to return the row index of the data frame by scanning **two or more** columns for the maximum.

To summarize, from the example below, I want to get the row:

```
11 building_footprint_sum 0.003 0.470
```

which holds the maximum of the data frame

```
+----+-------------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| id |        plot_name        | rsquare_allotments | rsquare_block_dev |
+----+-------------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|  6 | building_footprint_max  | 0.002              | 0.421             |
|  7 | building_footprint_mean | 0.002              | 0.354             |
|  8 | building_footprint_med  | 0.002              | 0.350             |
|  9 | building_footprint_min  | 0.002              | 0.278             |
| 10 | building_footprint_sd   | 0.003              | 0.052             |
| 11 | building_footprint_sum  | 0.003              | 0.470             |
+----+-------------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

Is there a rather simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Is it is certain that the max in each column will be at the same row?  If not, one of the columns will have to take priority, or you'll need some decision making rule like use the sum of the two columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `pmax`

```
?pmax    
pmax and pmin take one or more vectors (or matrices) as arguments and
return a single vector giving the ‘parallel’ maxima (or minima) of the vectors.
```

I would suggest making this in two steps

```
# make a new column that compares column 3 and column 4 and returns the larger value
> df$new <- pmax(df$rsquare_allotments, df$rsquare_block_dev)

# look for the row, where the new variable has the largest value
> df[(df$new == max(df$new)), ][3:4]
```

Consider that if the max value occurs more than once, your result will have more than one row

Comment: Well obviously I didn´t point out my problem exact enough. I want to scan the last two columns of my example dataframe above for the maximum value, not for the largest sum. When the maximum value of the dataframe is found the row containing the maximum value should be returned.

Comment: OK. But what is the maximum value of a data.frame with multiple columns?

Comment: Well as in the example above, the maximum value of the two columns is 0.470 (row 6, column 4). So this value has to be found and the row, where this maximum occurs should be returned, so that I can store the returned row in a new df.

Comment: Thank you @muc8 for your inspiration. However the command: `df$new <- pmax(df[3:4])` somehow returned a vector that was written in the first two rows of the new column. Then `df$new <- pmax(df$rsquare_allotments, df$rsquare_block_dev)` did the job. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Axel.Foley Just to clarify the different approaches: My solution provides the row, as you show in the desired output in your question (`I want to get the row`). However, your title implies, that you are looking for the row index. So in order to make everything clear, please edit your question (no more use of the word index), or accept the answer of Stephan if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Well, when asking this question I found it appropriate to have the index of the row containing the maximum. While playing around with your (@rmuc8) code it turned out that with modifying it a bit, I can come up with the complete row than only having the index of that row. Having the row is much better, in my case, than only getting the index of a row. So I edited the title to fit my question.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the row index in which a matrix attains its maximum. You can do this by using `which()` with the `arr.ind=TRUE` option:

```
> set.seed(1)
> foo <- matrix(rnorm(6),3,2)
> which(foo==max(foo),arr.ind=TRUE)
     row col
[1,]   1   2
```

So in this case, you would need row 1. (And you can discard the `col` output.)

If you go this route, be wary of floating point arithmetic and `==` (see FAQ 7.31). Better to do this:

```
> which(foo>max(foo)-0.01,arr.ind=TRUE)
     row col
[1,]   1   2
```

where you use an appropriate small value in place of 0.01.

Comment: Thank you for your advices, but it seems like there is a problem when dealing with dataframes that contain not only numeric values. When I attempt to use your code for my above mentioned dataframe it says: "only defined for a dataframe, with only numeric variables"

Comment: (1) Could you please edit your post to include a reproducible example, and to indicate what result would you like to see for the `max` operation if numeric and non-numeric data are mixed? (And comment here so I notice your edit) (2) I suspect that you will need to subset the relevant columns of your `data.frame`, e.g., `as.matrix(your.data.frame[,3:4])` - perhaps you can try this and see whether it helps.